# How can one Dispose() a Refit connection made w/ RestService.For<IRestInterface>

Tags: c#, refit

I am creating an interface for a REST API [using Refit](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit) as follows:

```
var settingsXml = new RefitSettings
{
    ContentSerializer = new XmlContentSerializer(new XmlContentSerializerSettings())
};
this.api = RestService.For<IRestInterface>(baseUrl, settingsXml);
```

Inside RestService.For() an HttpClient is created, How can I dispose this?